# How to make basic things in QGis

Tags: qgis

I'm working on an Optic Fiber distributer.
I'm currently looking to earn about QGis, just to add every client on a map of my country. But I don't really know how to do it. Can someone make a little tutorial like:

1. Add your city touching this, this and this
2. Import the position of your clients doing this this and this
   And so on.
   This is probably a stupid post, but I would like to make this!
   We have all clients geopositioned longitude and latitude.

Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: I think, that you need to tell more about your OS, QGIS version etc.

Comment: This sort of question is better asked at gis.stackexchange.com, most of it is already answered there